# Excel VBA Script for copying non-duplicate rows

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I am a VBA newbie to the point I can only copy and paste code and learn what it does by trial and error.

My need is a VBA code that will copy rows from Workbook A to Workbook B, the catch is that whenever it is copying rows from Workbook A to Workbook B, I need a way to make sure that the rows being copied over from Workbook A don't already exist in Workbook B. In other words, I don't want duplicate data being copied into Workbook B. Please help.

Comment: copy them all over and remove duplicates.

Comment: @Jeeped Agreed. Even from a VBA standpoint. Record the copying over and duplicate removing and then change the code around to suit your needs. It will be a fast way of doing it and you'll be able to maintain the code since you understand what you did.

Comment: I can point you in the right direction. First you need to find a unique identifier, like an order# for instance. Next you need to create two arrays or collections. Fill array1 with all wbA order numbers and corresponding row#s, and array2 with all wbB data and corresponding row#s. Then loop through all array1 and look to see if it's in array2. If it's not, move the row. 

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I know where I need to go now. #CodersBlock